# Make a Carbon object out of request input

Tags: php, laravel, date, laravel-5

How can I make use of the Carbon functionality with input from the request?

I am using a variable `$pre_Date` which comes from my request:

```
$pre_Date = Input::get('Date');
```

Now I want to add a month with the variable `$pre_Date`. I can use it with current date using `Carbon::now()->addMonth(1)`. How can i use addMonth() function for a variable $pre_Date which is not current date.

The format of $pre_Date variable is `'Y-m-d'`

Comment: You edited this a few minutes ago? What is wrong? Don't you have the answer already?

Comment: I have got the answer, but there is bad reputation of mine in asking question. I have to improve that. Stack Overflow don't give me any chance to ask question. it advises me to improve my past questions. If it is improved then it will give me to ask questions. So, I am trying........

Comment: Maybe you can start with accepting the right answer :)

Comment: Mr. Mark Walet, can you give your skype or email or blog. I am new comer in laravel. I am learning it. I need some suggestions. For developing purpose i need to chat with you, can you give me that. please

Comment: I recommend you start with an awesome series on laracasts: https://www.laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch-2017

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You first create a Carbon object from your string.

```
$date = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $Date);
$date->addMonth();
```

Comment: Thank you very much, brother.  @Jerodev it's working

Comment: Any way to have `Validator` do this conversion automatically for us, using some rule?

Comment: (So that we just need to call `->addMonth()` manually.)